# Pusher Channel subscription not working with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pusher

I am trying to build an [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) app.

It will be a basic chat app. It will communicate with a web portal that is using Pusher api.

As Ionic is also a hybrid framework trying to integrate pusher [Angular library](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-angular).

On development machine(System) it works fine channels subscription and events are working but after creating a build it doesn't work. I tried reading through forums but didn't get anything and I feel my code is correct as its working on dev machine.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work" ? Do you get any console errors? Does anything happen at all? Can you try adding some `console.log` calls so you get an idea of exactly where it's failing?

Comment: I tried using the console.log but there is no such errors when I tried channel.subscribe it fails silently but it works in the web. :|

Comment: If you fire up the app, can you open up the Pusher debug console in your browser and see if it logs any events? That will at least tell you if the app is able to connect.

Comment: Basically using slanger https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger but not receiving any events in logs :|

Answer (score 0):

There must be some authentication issue, check the headers are passed properly, also log the response from pusher auth request from your server endpoint,

```
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(status) {
  console.log(status)
});
```

And you can also try https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-js-iso instead of pusher.js.